# pop in dictionary of list python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have this python dictionary, I want to pop index0 element 'juan' from the unique key on the dict 'Resultados'.

```
data1 = {'Resultados':['juan','jose','carlos','pepe','ronny']}
```

How could I do?

I am using

```
data1.pop('Resultados'[0])
```

but is not working.

Comment: the issue here is that `'Resultados'[0]` takes precedence, so you're passing `data1.pop('R')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**it is not working** is not how you should describe the problem.  Show the actual error, and better yet, trying to understand it.

```
In [451]: data1.pop('Resultados'[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-451-b2afd8c8d64b>", line 1, in <module>
    data1.pop('Resultados'[0])
KeyError: 'R'
```

`'Resultados'[0]` is the first letter of the string, 'R'.  That isn't a valid key for that dict. Right?

Correct indexing:

```
In [456]: data1['Resultados']
Out[456]: ['juan', 'jose', 'carlos', 'pepe', 'ronny']
In [457]: data1['Resultados'][0]
Out[457]: 'juan'
```

or it you want to remove it from the dict value

```
In [459]: data1['Resultados'].pop(0)
Out[459]: 'juan'
In [460]: data1
Out[460]: {'Resultados': ['jose', 'carlos', 'pepe', 'ronny']}
```

When things don't work as expected, break the problem down into pieces, keeping in mind the order in which Python evaluates expressions.  That evaluation order should be one of the first things you learn about the language.

Comment: yeah, I guess I did not analyze it this way, which is the proper one by the way, thanks hpaulj

Answer (score 2):

```
data1['Resultados'].pop(0)
```

I guess?